# How to subscribe for a filter changed event in ag grid

Tags: ag-grid

I have a problem in which i need to display the number of rows filtered in ag grid at run time.

How can I subscribe for a filter changed event in ag grid(javascript version )?

Comment: You can use the `filterChanged` event. [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/)

Answer (score 18):

Ag grid has callbacks 'onFilterChanged' & 'onFilterModified'

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    enableFilter: true,
    onFilterChanged: function() {console.log('onFilterChanged');},
    onFilterModified: function() {console.log('onFilterModified');}
};
```

You can find more details here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/

Comment: What's the difference between changed and modified?

Comment: the documentation on `onFilterChanged`: "Filter has been modified and applied." vs on `onFilterModified`: "Filter was modified but not applied. Used when filters have 'Apply' buttons." – in summary, you probably want `onFilterChanged` if you want to do something based on the value of the filter setting

Answer (score 7):

I was searching for the way how to subscribe to the 'onFilterChange' event.
I need to track the number of rows on each filter change.
`filteredRows` is the field to be shown with number of filtered rows.

```js
this.gridOptions.api.eventService.addEventListener('filterChanged', (e) => {
  this.filteredRows = e.api.paginationGetRowCount();
})
```

Comment: This is the only way I was able to do it. (In a legacy Vue 2 project.) Where is this in the docs, does anyone know?

Comment: Anyway, I was left with the impression that their docs are VERY unintuitive to parse and navigate in order to actually find anything. Or I'm just dumb. =D

Answer (score 4):

For me, it helped to add a method to the filterChanged listener:

```
<ag-grid-angular
    ...
    [rowData]="rowData"
    (filterChanged)="onFilterChanged($event)"
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

Then I created a function that uses the params api to get the current displayed rows:

```
onFilterChanged(params: GridOptions): void {
console.log(this.numberOfRows = params.api?.getDisplayedRowCount());
```

}

I hope this helps anybody too.